# Rendering GeoJSON with LeafletJS how can I avoid line endings being connected?

Tags: javascript, leaflet, geojson

I am [rendering GeoJSON containing `LineStrings` on a Leaflet map](https://github.com/johnjohndoe/RROK). For some reason the end points of each path are connected like in a circle (see blue line in the screenshot).

[image: Blue line with connected ends]

Here is the relevant portion of code ..

```
renderGeoJson = function(link) {
    var url = $(link).attr("href");
    $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
        var feature = data.features[0];
        var color = nameToColor(feature.properties.name);
        var geojson = L.geoJson(data, {
            style: {
                type: "LineString",
                color: color,
                weight: 3,
                opacity: 0.75
            }
        });
        geojson.addTo(map);
    });
}
```

It may that the originial GeoJSON file has errors - it may be some option on Leaflet - please tell me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pointing to the specific GeoJSON file would make this answerable - would guess that it's an issue with the data since [other data in that repository has issues](https://github.com/johnjohndoe/RROK/blob/master/assets/s5.geojson).

Comment: True. I realized that this is not a Leaflet issue but a [problem with the GPX data from OpenStreetMap](http://gis.stackexchange.com/q/85918/7690). I forgot to close the question. Will do now.